# Cloud Architecture for Computationally Intensive Tasks

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am wondering what is the best practice to setup RESTful API for computationally intensive tasks using GCP.  For example, if I want to create a RESTful API to convert a .png file to a .jpg file based on imagemagick's convert command (i.e. `convert file.png file.jpg`).  Because the input file could be very large, the command may take up to a few minutes to complete.  How would I do it with GCP?

App engine is not enough because of the restricted environment and running time limit.  Compute engine would involve setting up web server, load balancer, task queue etc., which seems to be overkill for a simple API.

The solution I have in mind is simply to wrap the command `convert` inside a WSGI framework, and deploy it in app engine flexible environment.  Of course, when the `convert` command is invoked, it will use a lot of cpu and memory, which would make my web server slow.  But when this happens, app engine flexible will spin up more instances to handle new requests.  However, I have a feeling this is not the best solution.  I would like to know what is your approach on this problem.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use task queue for your use case so that you can control the scalability of servers.
Producer can load a job to task queue which contains details of images.
Task queue can in turn push the job to the URL end point configured.
So, the job would come to consumer where you can use imagemagick.

The main benefit of this design is you do not overload your servers. If all of your servers(consumers) are busy, the task remains in task queue (retry needs to be configured). When its an intensive task, other tasks can remain in queue until one of your servers(consumers) is ready to take it up.

P.S : Task queue can be either push or pull
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/taskqueue/push/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  So in summary, my front end would be a normal app engine that takes user requests and generates job to put on task queue.  Task queue pushes the job to a compute node (i.e. managed by container engine).  The compute node needs to implement REST api so task queue can communicate with it.  Once it received a job, it invoke the corresponding code to execute.